# Getting nordvpn status from within a python program

Tags: python, subprocess, vpn

I'm using the [`nordvpn_connect`](https://pypi.org/project/nordvpn-connect/) package to connect to VPN servers.

For example:

```py
from nordvpn_connect import initialize_vpn, rotate_VPN, close_vpn_connection

settings = initialize_vpn("uk2388")  # starts nordvpn and stuff
rotate_VPN(settings)  # actually connect to server

# ///// Stuff

close_vpn_connection(settings)
```

I would like to be able to check the status of the connection. From a terminal this is easily done with `nordvpn status`, but the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/nordvpn-connect/) doesn't mention anything like that.

So at the moment I'm just using `subprocess`:

```py
def check_vpn_status():
    """Check the VPN connection status by parsing the output of `nordvpn status` command."""
    try:
        output = subprocess.check_output(["nordvpn", "status"]).decode('utf-8')
        if "Status: Connected" in output:
            return True
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Error checking VPN status: {e}")
    return False
```

Is there a better way?